# Odd C behavior: variable visible when it shouldn't be

Tags: c, static, visibility

In my program, I have a file called `constants.h` that declares the following matrix in a global scope (the matrix should be fully constant - if anyone sees a potential problem, let me know):

```
static unsigned char const MY_MATRIX[66][9] = {...};
```

In another file, let's call it `main.c`, I can actually reference this constant:

```
doSomething(var1, count, MY_MATRIX[42], TRUE, FALSE, thing);
```

But then I just read the definition of the keyword `static` and it's *supposed* to mean that the variable *cannot* be accessed outside the file it's defined in. (In this case, the desired behavior is that it should be accessed, but then it seems the `extern` keyword is the one to use!)

So, can anyone tell me why this works? Why is the variable not invisible? Thanks!

Comment: I understand the semantics now, but I'd like to amend my original question: why would a static global variable in a .c file be visible to other compilation units anyway? I thought the implementation was always hidden from all other files.

Comment: The static global variable is not visible to other compilation units - if you define it in a .c file, other .c files are not going to see it. If you define it in a .h file, however, the C code from the header will be replicated in each .c file, creating a false illusion of visibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are declaring a `static` variable in a header: when you include the header in a C file, you get a brand-new definition independent of the other definitions. If you include the header in two files, you get two independent copies; if you include it in three C files, you get three independent copies, and so on. The copies do not conflict with each other, because the `static` definition hides them from the linker.

A proper way to make use of a shared piece of data allocated in a static memory is to make the declaration `extern` in the header, and then add a non-static definition in exactly one C file.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that! One last thing: is the matrix defined in that way fully constant (that is no element or the matrix itself can be changed)?

Comment: @user1866808 Yes, the matrix is constant, in the sense that the only way to change it involves undefined behavior through a cast (a very bad idea). Many modern compilers will crash when this happens. In practice, though, some compilers, especially the older ones, may let you change the matrix, and not crash in the process. Declaring the matrix `const` is the best you can do on your part.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I amended my question after I thought of something, see above. :)

Answer (score 2):

If it's in a header, it's defined in every single source file you include it in (though each source file will have their own instantiation of it - they don't access the same one).

Answer (score 1):

There are two uses of the static keyword:

- A static variable inside a function block keeps its value between subsequent calls.
- A static global variable or a function is "visible" only in the file it has been declared in.

Here, you define the matrix in a header file, hence it is visible to all the .c files which include that header file. To restrict its visibility, define it in a .c file instead.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when a static variable is declared in a header file its scope is not limited to .h file meaning nothing like **header file scope**. The translation unit includes the text from header file in source file. Therefore every translation unit including header file gets its own **individual** variable though it is static scope.